# Setting a minimum margin size with the geometry package

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry

When using the `geometry` and `fancyhdr` packages it is possible to specify margins that are too small to hold the header and footer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\geometry{vmargin=0.5in,
  head=\dimexpr1in+\dp\strutbox\relax,
  foot=\dimexpr1in+\dp\strutbox\relax}
\fancypagestyle{foo}{
  \fancyhead[L]{\rule{\textwidth}{1in}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{\textwidth}{1in}}}
\pagestyle{foo}
\begin{document}
This does not give any warning that the "margins"
are too small to hold the header and footer.
\end{document}
```

In my actual use case, I do not know the size of the header and footer in advance, although they are of constant size after `\begin{document}`. It is relatively easy to adjust the size of the header/footer to fit the content and `fancyhdr` warns you if the content does not fit. The issue is if the header/footer runs off the page, neither `fancyhdr` nor `geometry` warn you.

I would like to be able to specify that I want the margins to be either exactly 0.5 in or just big enough to hold the header/footer. In the case of the above MWE the margins should be 1 in (maybe the top margin should be a little bigger to include `\headsep`) instead of the 0.5 in that they are. The `includehead` option would give me a 1.5 in margin which is too big.

In the absence of being able to specify a minimum margin size, is it possible to at least raise a warning.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I  didn't recognise the aliases you're using. (Not really aliases - I just don't know what to call them.)

Comment: This is really a(nother) **geometry** bug, isn't it? It should at least warn you that it can't satisfy the equations given the specified values. Ideally, it should recalculate earlier values, if necessary, to accommodate later ones.

Comment: @cfr it might be a bug, but it is not obvious to me how to fix it or even get a warning (I think I can for the topmargin) but running off the bottom means I have to add all the lengths up.

Comment: I think for the bottom you are setting the wrong length aren't you? You don't want the `\footskip` to be 1"+. You want the bottom margin, less the `\footskip`, to be 1"+. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @cfr it depends what you call the bottom margin. In this example, there needs to be 1 in from the bottom edge of the paper to the bottom of the text.

Comment: Yes, but you've set 1" from the bottom of the text to the top of the footer.

Comment: @cfr `\footskip` is not the same as `\headsep`. I am pretty sure footstep is the distance from the bottom of the text to the bottom of the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the lengths at the beginning of the document and have **geometry** adjust the margin if necessary. I think that essentially you want to check that `tmargin` is at least `\headheight+\headsep+<some minimal value>`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr,calc}
\geometry{vmargin=0.5in,
  headheight=\dimexpr1in+\dp\strutbox\relax,
  footskip=\dimexpr1in+\dp\strutbox\relax,
  verbose,
  showframe
}
\fancypagestyle{foo}{%
  \fancyhead[L]{\rule{\textwidth}{1in}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{\textwidth}{1in}}}
\pagestyle{foo}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{\headheight+\headsep+5pt}%
  \ifdim\Gm@tmargin<\@tempdima\geometry{tmargin=\@tempdima}\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This does not give any warning that the `margins' are too small to hold the header and footer.
\end{document}
```

[image: 1" header]

Changing the definitions for the page layout and header for a .1" header as follows

```
\geometry{vmargin=0.5in,
  headheight=\dimexpr.1in+\dp\strutbox\relax,
  footskip=\dimexpr1in+\dp\strutbox\relax,
  verbose,
  showframe
}
\fancypagestyle{foo}{%
  \fancyhead[L]{\rule{\textwidth}{.1in}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{\textwidth}{1in}}}
\pagestyle{foo}
```

results in a 1/2" top margin

[image: .1in header with 1/2" margin]

And if the `headheight` is not large enough, of course, **fancyhdr** *will* warn you.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to do this for the bottom, too. But, in that case, I guess what's needed is to adjust `\textheight` but **geometry** won't allow that and ignores the adjustment on the grounds that it constitutes an attempt to over-specify.